# DP/HDMI to USB frame grabber internal cards

Tags: hdmi, display-port

The requirement is a HDMI to USB frame grabber internal card or a DisplayPort to USB frame grabber internal.

So far I have found DP/HDMI to PCIe frame grabber internal cards. http://www.unigraf-china.cn/en/products/dp-compliance-test-hardware/ufg-04-dp/ https://www.unigraf.fi/products/frame-grabbers/ufg-07-hsdp https://www.epiphan.com/products/dvi2pcie-duo/

Or is there a converter for sending the PCIe data from these cards across a USB port. In other words,is there a PCIe to USB converter ?

Comment: There *are* HDMI capture cards that connect to USB, but you said something about *"internal"*. What do you mean by *"internal"* if PCIe is not what you want? Also, *"Is there a PCIe to USB converter?"* -- That does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By "internal", I meant as system on chips (SoC) or ICs. Is there such chips ?                                                                   Thanks for clarifying that PCIe to USB converter does not exist.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way you're using "internal", but *every* capture card, whether it connects to USB or PCIe has its own SoC to do the capturing/encoding, that's just how they work. So to clarify things further, do you actually need the SoC itself for making custom hardware, or do you need a product that *uses* that kind of SoC and connects to USB? (Like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Capture-Broadcast-Streaming-Grabber-Converter/dp/B0779ZJZX3)?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need the SoC itself for making custom hardware.